# How to set default image properties for an image in Sitecore RTE?

Tags: sitecore

I have a requirement where I have to set the default properties of all the images in RTE. For example, I want to set a margin of 5px for all images in my RTE. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For that specific example - setting a margin of 5px on every image - you should do that with CSS, not with the margin settings in the Sitecore RTE.

Develop your HTML in such a way that you have a consistent wrapper for all images that would be rendered on the page coming from an RTE field.  Target image tags inside the class for said wrapper and style your image tags with the amount of margin you want.